# Oracle SQL cascading information across multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

The below table represents customer owned a vehicle from 2000 to 20XX. I am trying to create output from the below table such that since the customer has vehicle from 2000 to 2001 it is automatically passed on to next year ie 2002 to 2003 and so on.I tried using lead lag analytical function but it can  pass on to next row only.

Kindly guide if if can implement this cascading effect without a stored procedure.

```
customer  vehicle    start  end 
--------------------------------------
A            0        2000   2001
A            1       2002   2003
A            1        2003   2004
A            0        2004   2015 .....contd
```

Expected output

```
customer  vehicle    start  end 
------------------------------------
A            0        2000   2001
A            1        2002   2003
A            2        2003   2004
A            2        2004   2005 ...contd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select customer,
       max(vehicle) over (partition by customer order by start) as vehicle,
       start, end
from table t;
```

If you want a cumulative sum (which I'm pretty sure was not in the original queation), just use `sum()` instead of `max()`:

```
select customer,
       sum(vehicle) over (partition by customer order by start) as vehicle,
       start, end
from table t;
```

Comment: No, I want reslt of first row to add to second row, and the new value of second roe to third row .. etc.. like cascading

Comment: thanks gordon, let me check it out . I always thought that sum with analytical func will all give only sum of all values within defined partition across all rows

Comment: @Awknewbie . . . With an `order by` clause it turns into a cumulative sum.